# WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, jwt

i want to use jsonwebtoken, but after i've tried implement it, it gives me this error:WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

I cant see whats wrong with the code. im not able to do anything on the localhost as it looses connection all the time.

Client
chat.js

```
 const socket = io({
    extraheaders: {
      token : sessionStorage
    }
    });
```

Server
app.js

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
  const {token}= socket.handshake.auth.headers;
  if (token && token ===sessionStorage){
    return next();
  }
  next(new Error('Pls login again'))
  

 .on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log(token)
    // Connection now authenticated to receive further events
    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        io.emit('message', message);
        console.log(socket.handshake.auth.headers)

    });
   

  

[![Localstorage][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YewlR.png
```

Comment: Problems can be with nginx conf or pm2 cluster mode.